vscode 1.88.* marks new errors in my typescript, but tsx and bun run it correctly
I just updated vscode to 1.88.1 and some errors appeared in my ts code that weren't there days ago. (or maybe 1.88 broke it?)
This is my project: https://github.com/Drean64/fass
I get basic errors like this, on lines that have been working since the project start:

When I run this with node+tsx or bun it works just fine.
The antlr4 dependency didn't change either.
Any ideas?
